# In Amazon Web Services what does AMI number signify

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am trying to create an Amazon EC2 instance. I want to create a micro, 64-bit, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS instance.

In Amazon Web Services I have seen all instance have `AMI` numbers. Now I found two ami(s) with numbers `ami-8a7f3ed8` and `ami-b8a8e9ea`. both looks same to me - micro, ebs-based, 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04LTS images.

If so, what is the difference and why two number for the same machine image?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11937357/in-amazon-web-services-what-does-ami-number-signify

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AMIs are machine images.  They are essentially snapshots that you can use to create a new instance.  It is possible to have 2 snapshots that have exactly the same data.

For instance, you can create an AMI from an existing instance to get a new AMI with a new number.  Each time you repeat the process for the machine, you will create another AMI with a different number.  If nothing has changed on the source machine, all of these AMIs will be virtually identical.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the AMI IDs don't signify anything in particular, but are specific to regions, so an otherwise identical US-WEST AMI will have a different ID from a US-EAST one, and so on.

If you're using Ubuntu, you may want to look at the official Ubuntu AMIs:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EC2StartersGuide#Official_Ubuntu_Cloud_Guest_Amazon_Machine_Images_.28AMIs.29

Answer (score 0):

AMI ID is a combination of OS, architecture, ebs, zone and it's release.  You should check if the zones/regions are also identicaly for the AMI's you listed.